# Visual emails from Send Grid have an unwanted text header and appear graphically twice

Tags: html-email, sendgrid

[image]On sending out test emails from Send Grid, unwanted text appears at the top of the email which appears to have come from my webiste, and the graphical design template appears twice?

Please see screenshot

Any suggestions most welcome

Thank you

I believed that a single email with no extra text or a double image would end up in my test emall box

Comment: What screenshot are you referring to?

Comment: Crap, lol, seems the uploaded screenshot hasn't been attached. Let me try again.